# tag postgres image used in docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, tags

I have the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  bejebeje-identity:
    build:
      context: ./Bejebeje.Identity
      labels:
        com.bejebeje.description: "Bejebeje's Identity Server"
    image: bejebeje/identity:latest
    ports:
      - "5006:443"
      - "5005:80"
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/
  database:
    image: postgres:13.0
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

When I run `docker-compose build .` the images are built, I then run `docker image ls` and I get:

[image: docker image ls]

I suspect the `<none>` image is the postgres database? In my `docker-compose` file, how can I tag the database image with something like `database/bejebeje/identity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'none' was not postgres image but related to bejebeje-identit and only lead by dockerfile.

There is multistage build mode in docker. It will create multi stage docker images.
You can find below line from the project dockerfile.

```
# copy the contents of /app/out in the `build-env` and paste it in the
# `/app` directory of the new runtime container.
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
```

that's reason.
Just rewrite your dockerfile, and remove the previous stage image. Then you will not see 'non' tagged image again.